# Zend Db Cascading Delete

Tags: database, zend-framework, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to figure this out,

I have three tables (Table A, Table B, Table C)
Table A is parent of B, and B is parent of C.

I built the relationships properly by setting

```
$_dependentTables & $_referenceMap appropriately
```

so when I update/delete lets say a row from A, the corresponding affected rows in B gets updated/deleted also. Similarly if I delete a row from B, the corresponding affected rows in C gets updated/deleted.

HOWEVER, if I delete from A, and rows in B gets deleted, the rows that should be deleted in C does not get deleted!!!!!

Is this because the zend cascading feature does not support cascading to that full extend or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason it does not cascade beyond one relation is because after calling `Zend_Db_Table_Row::delete()`, it will retrieve the dependent tables and call `Zend_Db_Table::_cascadeDelete()`. Within `_cascadeDelete()` it will build a where clause and use `Zend_Db_Table::delete()` to delete one or more records.

To allow true cascade deletion, you should rewrite `_cascadeDelete()` to first retrieve a rowset of affected records, loop through the set and call `delete()` on each row.